# I have a problem in inserting the vector symbol

Tags: symbols, vector

I have a problem with \vec command: instead of the vector symbol it inserts the tilde. I don't see what part of the code is wrong: `$$\mathbf{\Gamma(\vec{B}) = \mu_0 I + \frac{d\phi(\vec{E})}{dt}}$$`.

Comment: I don't get any tilde, though your code is strange in many ways (do you really want vectors *both* bold and with an arrow?) Please provide a short minimal code reproducing the issue, and maybe explain how the equation is supposed to look like.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide complete small document, which reproduce your problem. In my math testbed (used  `stix` fonts doesn't reproduce your problem. BTW, `$$` is not LaTeX instruction, rather TeX primitive. Please use `\[` and `\]` instead or `\begin{equation*}`  ... `\end{equation}`

Comment: What's the reason for the `\mathbf` encompassing the whole formula?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is `\mathbf` encompassing the whole formula, which is wrong and makes no sense whatsoever, because it *doesn't* make the formula bold, but just uses various symbols without a proper meaning.

[image]

If you want to make a formula bold for emphasizing it (but you shouldn't), use `\bm`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\begin{document}

\[
\bm{\Gamma(\vec{B}) = \mu_0 I + \frac{d\phi(\vec{E})}{dt}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, however, that boldface in math doesn't carry the meaning of emphasis.

Comment: Thank you very much, effectively I can remove the boldface.